# Post data and file together to Laravel API using Guzzle

Tags: php, laravel, guzzle

I've two working project communicating between each other via an API built in a Laravel. So far there is only simple POST requests made with GuzzleHttp 6.

And I am currently trying to have a new POST request made from 1 to 2, which would send a couple of simple fields along with one file.
Project 1 has a form, on the form submit I handle the data and want to send them to project 2 via a POST request to this new API endpoint.

I've tried different guzzle options 'multipart', 'form_data' etc  and realised they may not be combined together. Now I understood that this options are exclusive and using only "multipart" seems the way to go. 
But when I send my request to Laravel no data nor file are there.

Here is the code for my request

```
$options = ‌[
  'multipart' => 
  [
    [
      'name' => 'data',
      'contents' => '{"field_1":"Test","field_2":"Test","field_3":"Test"}',
      'headers' => 
        [
            'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
        ],
    ],
    [
      'name' => 'file',
      'filename' => 'test.pdf',
      'Mime-Type' => 'application/pdf',
      'contents' => file_get_contents($_FILEs['text_file']['temp_name']),
    ]
  ]
];

$this->client->request('POST', "api/test_post", $options)
```

I also gve this a try:

```
$options = ‌[
  'multipart' => 
  [
    [
      'name' => 'field_1',
      'contents' => 'Test',
    ],
    [
      'name' => 'field_2',
      'contents' => 'Test',
    ],
    [
      'name' => 'file',
      'filename' => 'test.pdf',
      'Mime-Type' => 'application/pdf',
      'contents' => fopen($_FILEs['text_file']['temp_name'],'r'),
    ]
  ]
];

$this->client->request('POST', "api/test_post", $options)
```

If I look the request content on the receiving end, nothing is there. No field or file.

I've seen couples posts, some say to include headers some say not too. I kinda got lost and amd now running out of ideas.

I would expecet the infos to be as if they where form post I guess:

- $request->inpust('field_1') -> 'test'
- $request->inpust('field_2') -> 'test'
- $request->inpust('field_3') -> 'test'
- $request->file('file') -> my uploaded file

Also I should point out that I am not exactly sure how multipart/form-data works, so that might not help me.

If you can point me to the right direction, that would help a lot

Comment: `$_FILEs['text_file']` isn't going to work, 1) because it should be `$_FILES` and 2) because `$_FILES['text_file']` is probably an array if used correctly, not a path to a file. Perhaps you meant `$_FILES['text_file']['tmp_name']` if you haven't moved the uploaded file?

Comment: Yes my bad it was simply a error on my part when I wrote the quesiton, I actually use file_get_contents($_FILES['text_file']['tmp_name']) as you said

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I finally figured it out. The second example from above is the way to go also be sure to check the headers of the request and the client...

As this API has been running for quite some time and was only doing json type requests, the Client was instantiated with

```
$options = [
  headers => [ 'Content-Type' => 'application/json']
]
```

Which, as stated in multiple answers across the internet, prevents Guzzle to automatically set the Content-Type depending of the request options.

In my case, removing this line made Guzzle enable to set it properly when provided with 'multipart' option.

Also, as all other requests are using the 'json' options, Guzzle also works it's magic and set 'Content-Type' => 'application/json' as well.